# Deleting value for selected collectionview in coredata?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have local gallery in my app(I took id of video on coredata and save data to local). When I click the cell, it opens in another view then start playing video. On this view I have button for delete video. I want to delete it on my coredata

```
    func getListdata()  {
        /////////// Getting list of videos from coredata ///////
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Videos", in: managedContext)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        

        listArr = try? managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as NSArray
        videolist.reloadData()
    }
```

```
func saveVideo(outputUrl: URL) {
        let video_id = NSUUID().uuidString
        let video_data : NSData? = NSData(contentsOf: outputUrl)
        Common().saveVideoInDocumentDirectory(video_id, VideoData: video_data)
        
        
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
        
        //////// saving video id to coredata  ///////
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let videoEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Videos", into: managedContext) as! Videos
        videoEntity.video_id = video_id
        try? managedContext.save()
    }
```

```
func saveVideoInDocumentDirectory(_ VideoPath: String!, VideoData: NSData!) {
        
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let paths = (getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(VideoPath)
        print(paths)
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: paths){
            VideoData?.write(toFile: paths, atomically: false)
        } else {
            print("File is already saved with this name")
        }
    }
```

```
func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }
```